# Error text is going out of the Screen in material textfields

Tags: ios, mdc-components

I am using Material Textfield for my project,

```
@IBOutlet weak var cellTextField: MDCTextField!
func setUpCellUI() {
    cellTextField.clearButton.isHidden = true
    cellTextField.font = CSFont.fontWithName(.Medium, size: 17)
    cellTextField.textColor = UIColor.contSyncTextLightColor()
    textFieldControllerFloating = MDCTextInputControllerLegacyDefault(textInput: cellTextField)
}
```

and error I am setting as

```
self.textFieldControllerFloating.setErrorText(error.errorString, errorAccessibilityValue: nil)
```

if error message is long text is going out of the screen, How can I fix this ? See the following image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this by setting the number of line for `leadingUnderlineLabel`

```
MDCTextField *textField = [[MDCTextField alloc] init];
textField.leadingUnderlineLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
textField.leadingUnderlineLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/releases/tag/v93.2.0

Answer (score 0):

This is a known, still open, [issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/issues/1924).